# How do I handle exceptions thrown from VB.NET class library within SSIS package?

Tags: vb.net, ssis

We are using a library created in VB.NET in SSIS - Script Task to carry out various database related activities.

How do I force the SSIS package to fail when the VB.NET class library invoke from within the package throws an exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlintegrationservices/thread/4ca66ffa-0005-40fe-96aa-58b1959a8120/

"Depending on how you have the rest of your package configured, you have the following options (maybe more):

1. Return failure using (C#) `Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;`, or (VB.Net) `Dts.TaskResult = CInt(ScriptResults.Failure)`
2. Throw an error with (C#) `throw new Exception()`, or (VB.Net) `Throw (New Exception())`

Option 1 requires that the rest of your components be connected to the Script via a Success precedence constraint."

Comment: Try catch block should be added to the script component. Call your library project inside the try block, if there are any exception thrown in the block will be catch and set the Dts.TaskResult to failure. So that entire package execution will be failed.